# I need help excluding a portion of my style.css on mobile.css

Tags: html, css

A portion of my style.css directs my site to randomly align photos left and right. While this looks great on desktop, I'd like to exclude it for mobile devices because it doesn't look good. Here is the code from my style.css

```
/*---Start automatic align left and right of the blog post randomly----*/
.post-list:nth-child(odd) img{
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
}

.post-list:nth-child(even) img{
float:right;
margin-left:20px;
}

.post-list img.wp-post-image{
width:auto !important;
height:180px !important;
}

.post-list:nth-child(odd) iframe{
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
}

.post-list:nth-child(even) iframe{
float:right;
margin-left:20px;
}

.post-list iframe{
max-width:100%;

/*---Start automatic dis-align left and right of the blog post randomly--*/
body.category-8 .post-list:nth-child(odd) img{
float:none;
margin-right:0;
}

body.category-8 .post-list:nth-child(even) img{
float:none;
margin-left:0;
}
body.category-8 .post-list:nth-child(odd) iframe{
float:none;
margin-right:0;
}

body.category-8 .post-list:nth-child(even) iframe{
float:none;
margin-left:0;
}

body.category-8 .post-list img.wp-post-image{
width: auto !important;
height:180px !important;
}
body.category-8 img.frm_ajax_loading{
max-width:16px !important;
}
/*---End automatic dis-align left and right of the blog post randomly----*/
```

How would I exclude this function from occurring on mobile devices?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need jQuery to check if the user is viewing on a mobile device, and use `removeClass` to exclude the CSS.

Comment: Just as a note, CSS doesn't use functions.  CSS is basically a file to design the elements before even loading, so none of it is a function.  Meanwhile, jQuery applies classes a few milliseconds after the document is ready and the timing can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You would put media queries in your stylesheets. For example this media query will check that the browser window is at least 480px, above iPhone portrait, this value can be changed off course. Then it runs this code.

If the browser window is less than 480px wide it will not run that code.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
   /*---Start automatic align left and right of the blog post randomly----*/
.post-list:nth-child(odd) img{
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
}

.post-list:nth-child(even) img{
float:right;
margin-left:20px;
}

.post-list img.wp-post-image{
width:auto !important;
height:180px !important;
}

.post-list:nth-child(odd) iframe{
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
}

.post-list:nth-child(even) iframe{
float:right;
margin-left:20px;
}

.post-list iframe{
max-width:100%;
}
}
```

Here is a great article on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) if you want to find out more about what screen sizes you would like to target.

Comment: do I need to add another '}' at the end? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Sorry I'm such a rook, but which file is that in wp? I have style.css, mobile.css, a few page loops.php and a functions.php

Comment: I don't know much about wp, but replacing your provided code with my solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be using HeadJS to load different CSS files based on conditionals; say if it is desktop load desktop.css and if it's mobile load mobile.css.

More at : https://github.com/headjs/headjs